# Copied database from live server doesn't allow me to perform inserts

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

After I copied the SQL Server database from the server and changed the connection string, the database appears to be read-only, but I try inserting a new node it gives me this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table
>   'Theshuk.dbo.Banners'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The
>   statement has been terminated.

This does not occur when I use the live server's database.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have seen some weird things like that in the identity not sticking around in a database migration.  not sure the cause, but it sounds like you are probably just missing an identity that was there in the other location.  check all your tables to see that you have identities specified where you expect them.

Answer (score 0):

The error just means: you cannot insert the values that you're trying to insert. As the error clearly states:

> **Cannot insert the value NULL** into column 'ID', table
>   'Theshuk.dbo.Banners'; **column does not allow nulls.**

So it seems you're trynig to insert something into that table, and the table requires a value for `ID` and you're not supplying one.

That's all there is - add that column and a value for it to your `INSERT` statement and you should be fine.